# Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [_timestamp : {enabled=true}]

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I am trying to setup the following mapping for ES 6.6.0, but I get this error;  `Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_timestamp : {enabled=true}]`

I think this originally came from ES2, but I can't be sure. There were some issues with incorrect types, so I've changed `string` to `keyword` for properties `ActionName` and `UserName`.

```
{
    "template": "audit_*",
    "aliases": {
        "{index}_read": {},
        "{index}_write": {},
        "{index}_verify": {}
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
                "number_of_shards": 12,
                "number_of_replicas": 2
        },
        "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "str_search_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "substring"
                            ]
                    },
                    "str_index_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "substring"
                            ]
                    },
                    "lwhitespace": {
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                            ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "substring": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram": 20
                    }
                }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "audit": {
                "dynamic_templates": [
                    {
                    "raw": {
                        "match_pattern": "regex",
                        "path_match": "Details\\.auditElement\\..*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                            "Raw": {
                                "analyzer": "lwhitespace",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                            }
                        },
                        "match_mapping_type": "string"
                    }
                    },
                    {
                    "newvalue": {
                        "match_pattern": "regex",
                        "path_match": ".*\\.newValue$",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                            "Raw": {
                                "analyzer": "lwhitespace",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    {
                    "oldvalue": {
                        "match_pattern": "regex",
                        "path_match": ".*\\.oldValue$",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                            "Raw": {
                                "analyzer": "lwhitespace",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    {
                    "analytics_text": {
                        "match_pattern": "regex",
                        "path_match": ".*\\.#text$",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                            "Raw": {
                                "analyzer": "lwhitespace",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                ],
                "_timestamp": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "_size": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "properties": {
                    "ActionName": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "index": true
                    },
                    "TimeStamp": {
                       "type": "date",
                       "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                    },
                    "UserName": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "index": true
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct, the `_timestamp` meta-field [was deprecated in 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-timestamp-field.html):

> The `_timestamp` field is deprecated. Instead, use a normal `date` field and set its value explicitly

Moreover, [`_size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.6/mapper-size.html) meta-field might not work as well since it requires mapper size plugin to be installed.

If you don't need these fields you should remove them from the mapping.

I suppose you will also have to update the types in the dynamic mappings as well (replace `string` with `keyword` or `text`).

Hope that helps!